# DRF browsable API is not working in "django-rest-passwordreset" package

Tags: django, api, browsable

I am currently using [django-rest-passwordreset](https://github.com/anx-ckreuzberger/django-rest-passwordreset) package but when I go to reset-password endpoint DRF browsable API is not working (package doc mentioned that browsable API support is available).

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password-reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
]
```

Is there any settings that I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

remove all default authentication and permission  class from setting.py and try

Answer (score 0):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
)
```

}

surly you add this to you setting,py remove this BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication. if still not working post question with the browseble image

Comment: I checked this and commented settings authentication method. Nothing has changed!